# jQuery widget factory with namespaces - no effect in jQuery.fn

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In jQuery.ui.widget, the widget factory, what are namespaces good fore if in the end the widget.bridge pollutes `jQuery.fn` with the widget, not considering the namespace?

Example widget: `$.widget( 'mynamespace.mywidget', { ... } );`

will create a new prototype in `$.mynamespace.mywidget` - so far so good.

But then, I'd really expect to also use the namespace like `$('...').mynamespace.mywidget()` rather than just `$('...').mywidget()` in case I define the widget with a namespace. Why is it not like this by default, is it not recommended to have something like this perhaps?

It feels wrong that the bridge thing is done automatically in widget factory. I guess it's possible to move the bridge afterwards, but by then whatever was in $.fn.mywidget before will be overwritten already.

Answer (score 0):

If you had two widgets of the same name you could just manually create the bridge under a different name like this:

```
$.widget('my.widget', {  });
$.widget('your.widget', {  });

$.widget.bridge('widget2', $.my.widget);
```

Which would then give you $.fn.widget and $.fn.widget2 so both can be used. The namespace just ensures that you don't overwrite the constructor function should two widgets have the same name.